# How can I console.log the Array object?

Tags: javascript

I want to view the array object and see the code for all the methods like `push()` and `length()`

How can I do this? Or is this not possible because the methods aren't written in Javascript?

Either way I want to console.log the object for fun

Comment: Here's the source of the V8 engine used by Chrome: https://github.com/v8/v8 What you want isn't possible in a browser.

Comment: You can't view the inner workings of native functions via the console.